# How do I get started building a personal assistant on Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, voice-recognition

The phrase kernel development came up a lot when doing research, but other people mentioned C++/Python. What would I need in order to get started with this creative project? (not for commercialization)

Overview of my project

1. Speech recognition - not one for commercialization, only to recognize my own voice and to open folders, files, and programs using my voice.
2. Web crawling/scraping - I want to dabble with how to web crawl (purely for the educative experience. Again, this is not intended for a commercial project).
3. Storing and retrieving information into a database - I'm familiar with Ms Access's interface and also SSRS/SQL. Might there be something similar to use with Linux?
4. Opening and closing programs in the background while I work on something else.

Answer (score 1):

Dude, you asked on dozen forums, already
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686328/what-language-do-i-need-to-program-a-personal-assistant-on-ubuntu) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266208/is-it-possible-to-create-my-own-personal-assistant-in-linux)

The answer is very simple:

1. Learn Python. Yes, you need to learn it
2. Download [Jasper](http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/) assistant from Github
3. Extend it with the features you need

Comment: Just from your second point you've already doubled the amount of info I've gotten across ALL the sites I've asked on. Thank you.